# circle progress bar css

Tags: css, svg, ionic-framework, css-shapes

I want to create a circle bar which stroke will be getting thicker as it progress.
Is it possible using css, or svg which can run on ionic mobile app.

Here is the what I want to achieve :

[image]

and here is [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/xamobipuke/edit?html,css,output) for starting point :

```css
.wrap {
  background: #0b1626;
  padding: 2em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Arial Black';
}
.knob {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1.5em;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #e84d51;
}
.knob .val {
  padding-top: 1em;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="knob">
    <div class="stats">
      <p class="val">16,858<br>1,285</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How should the circle animate? Should it just turn round and round?

Comment: it should go from 0 to 100% clock wise and should stop once reached starting point

Comment: @Saqueib That doesn't answer the question. Please provide illustrations showing the animation states at 0%, 50% and 100%.

Comment: Doubtful if this possible with basic HTML & CSS as there would be no method to animate the circular border width at along a path. Even SVG might be problematical without a significant amount of Javascript attached. Hence this question is probably too broad for this venu.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage here is a reference for you guys http://codepen.io/cliffpyles/pen/xbsiC similar but stroke must get thicker as it progress

Comment: @Saqueib I think we're all aware of what an ordinary circular progress meter looks like. You're asking for something different, but so far you still haven't adequately explained what you're trying to achieve. See my earlier comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my attempt. There is a lot of divs, but I didn't had the time to try to reduce them.

Basically, it plays with offsets between one circle and the other.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.moving {
  animation: rotatel 8s 1s linear forwards; /* to keep both animations the same */
}

.left .moving {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(200% - 70px);
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
  right: 15px;
  top: 20px;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: red;
  border-right-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

@keyframes rotatel {
   from {transform: rotate(-135deg);}
   50%, 100% {transform: rotate(45deg);}
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.right .moving {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(200% - 50px);
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  left: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: red;
  border-right-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  animation-name: rotater;
}

@keyframes rotater {
   0%, 50% {transform: rotate(45deg);}
   100% {transform: rotate(225deg);}
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  border: red solid 1px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="left">
    <div class="moving"></div>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div class="moving"></div>
</div>
<div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

As an aside, an exmple about achieving the underlying shape in a div, using borders an a pseudoelement

```css
.test1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 10px;
  border-bottom-width: 20px;
  border-left-width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
}

.test1:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 0px solid green;
  border-left-width: 30px;
  border-top-width: 40px;
  border-radius: 100% 0px 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1"></div>
```

Comment: looking cool, just wanted animation to stop once reached starting point

Comment: Just remove **infinite** from animation. It will execute only once

Comment: Nice one. I hadn't understood the same thing about the animation though.

Comment: @web-tiki Thanks !  And yes, the question (as noted in the comments) wasn't well explained.

Comment: Changed a little the snippet. Now it runs only once, and is a little bit delayed. I have also unified the animation properties in one point, so it's easier to change

Comment: for anyone interested: non-offset straight-up circular one based on the OP's first snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/aouLbw7L/11/

Answer (score 0):

## Try to use this line of code for progress bar

```css
@keyframes growProgressBar {
  0%, 33% { --pgPercentage: 0; }
  100% { --pgPercentage: var(--value); }
}

@property --pgPercentage {
  syntax: '<number>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
}

div[role="progressbar"] {
  --size: 12rem;
  --fg: #f00;
  --bg: #def;
  --pgPercentage: var(--value);
  animation: growProgressBar 3s 1 forwards;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(closest-side, white 80%, transparent 0 99.9%, white 0),
    conic-gradient(var(--fg) calc(var(--pgPercentage) * 10%), var(--bg) 0)
    ;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: calc(var(--size) / 5);
  color: var(--fg);
}

div[role="progressbar"]::before {
  counter-reset: percentage var(--value);
  content: counter(percentage) '/10';
}

/* demo */
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="--value:8"></div>
```